# Small object detection using deep learning

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have to count the number of checked and unchecked boxes in a paper sheet.The size of the checkbox is very small.Which will be the best object detection algorithms for this or any other approach.I have some images on which I can do customized training.Note my task is only object detection & recognition not localization.One approach is to extract the portion of the image which is containing the check boxes & apply contours to classify which is checked or unchecked.My question how I will extract that portion of an image which is containing scanned document or sheet.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to use **Convolutional Neural Network** it is the best object detection algorithm that I have ever used, although the matter of small objects this algorithm is so good at identifying small hidden patterns so, I think its work best for you, just try it.

Comment: You should have to use ResNet